# how to make UIVIEW in custom style?

Tags: swift

[image]

i have to make this type of UIView and there is a image view in the top.
i am new in swift so kindly suggest me the best Answer for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that there are many resources on how to design views in swift. But to give you quick advice, the first method is use storyboard and place an image with proper constraints.
The second one is to do it programmatically, by implementing UIView variable and assigning an image to id. Something like this:

```
private func constructView() {             
        let myImage = UIImageView(image: "name of image inserted to assets folder in xcode")
        myImage.frame = CGRect(x: 200, y: 64, width: 30, height: 30)
        container.addSubview(myImage)
    }
```